# jscrollpane - addHoverFunc - only works for the first element

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I tried to assign jscrollpane to two divs (.scrollpane). But unfortunately the function to show the scrollbar only on hover just works fine for the first element. The second one is allways visible.

```
$(function() {
                var $el                 = $('.scrollpane').jScrollPane({
                    verticalGutter  : 16
                }), 
                    extensionPlugin     = {

                        extPluginOpts   : {
                            mouseLeaveFadeSpeed : 500,
                            hovertimeout_t      : 1000,
                            useTimeout          : true,
                            deviceWidth         : 980
                        },
                        hovertimeout    : null,
                        isScrollbarHover: false,
                        elementtimeout  : null,
                        isScrolling     : false,

                        addHoverFunc    : function() {

                            if( $(window).width() ').css({
                                position    : 'absolute',
                                left        : $vBar.css('left'),
                                top         : $vBar.css('top'),
                                right       : $vBar.css('right'),
                                bottom      : $vBar.css('bottom'),
                                width       : $vBar.width(),
                                height      : $vBar.height()
                            }).bind('mouseenter.jsp',function() {

                                clearTimeout( instance.hovertimeout );
                                clearTimeout( instance.elementtimeout );

                                instance.isScrollbarHover   = true;

                                instance.elementtimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                                    $vBar.stop( true, true ).jspmouseenter();
                                }, 100 );   

                            }).bind('mouseleave.jsp',function() {

                                clearTimeout( instance.hovertimeout );
                                instance.isScrollbarHover   = false;
                                instance.hovertimeout = setTimeout(function() {

                                    if( !instance.isScrolling )
                                            $vBar.stop( true, true ).jspmouseleave( instance.extPluginOpts.mouseLeaveFadeSpeed || 0 );
                                    }, instance.extPluginOpts.hovertimeout_t );

                            });

                            $vBar.wrap( $vBarWrapper );

                        }

                        }


                    },

                    jspapi          = $el.data('jsp');




                $.extend( true, jspapi, extensionPlugin );
                jspapi.addHoverFunc();



            });
```

Comment: Have you tried walking through each $('.scrollpane') using $.each() ?